# C++ error C2040: 'ip' : 'const char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'std::string'?

Tags: c++, char, ip, constants

ive been going at this for hours I just cant figure it out, can someone help me out here?

```
cout << "Please enter the port to listen on: ";
int port = 2232;
cin >> port;
cout << "Please enter your ip address: ";
string addr;
cin >> addr; //ERROR 1
puts("");
WSAData wsa;
WORD Version = MAKEWORD(2,1);
WSAStartup(Version, &wsa);
SOCKET Listen = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
SOCKET Connect = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
SOCKADDR_IN Server;
Server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(addr); //ERROR 2
```

1   error C2040: 'ip' : 'const char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'std::string'

2   IntelliSense: no suitable conversion function from "std::string" to "const char *" exists

Comment: did you include <string> header?

Answer (score 1):

This is because [`inet_addr`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/inet_addr.html) takes a `const char*`, and you are passing a `std::string`. Call `c_str()` to do the conversion, like this:

```
Server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(addr.c_str());
```

The second error message simply tells you that the standard library does not have a way to perform this conversion implicitly.

Comment: that solved the second error, but the first one is still active.